# How does apkpure convert iPhone apps?

Tags: android, iphone

There is an app for the iPhone that is not available for Android. Yet, APKPure has it listed as an .apk.

It doesn't work, I tried to install it but got an error about parsing the value.

My question is - how do they convert the files? Is it even a legitimate conversion? Or just for clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Code of that apk if not then generate a code of apk through online code generator through apk then try Xamirin tool, just open code on that tool and make changes what you want and then simply clicked convert to ios may be this tool help you alot

Comment: Would obtaining the code be difficult? Could any knowledgeable person get it?

Comment: if you have some knowledge of ios or android may be its not very difficult for you.